# jQuery options keys from variable

Tags: jquery, variables, key, tablesorter

I'm using [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html) and need to disable the sorting on some columns.

**I can add options**

In my case I need to add the column numbers 1 and 2 below, from a variable, like I did with `my_number`. 1 and 2 work but not `my_number` (which is set to 3).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var my_number = 3;
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: { 
            1: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            2: { 
                sorter: false 
            },
            my_number: {
                sorter: false
            },
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@koskoz gave you the correct answer, so please give him credit. I wanted to show you the full example of how to use it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var my_headers = {
        1: { sorter: false },
        2: { sorter: false }
    },
    my_number = 3;

    my_headers[my_number] = { sorter : false };

    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: my_headers
    });

});
```

And share an alternative with you. I've forked a [copy of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) which allows you to just add a class name to the header like `sorter-false` to disable sorting of that column. Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use variable as key in JSON.

Try something like this instead:

```
headers[my_number] = { sorter: false }
```